# Why come NullPointerException?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am developing openGL live wallpaper using Robert Green GLWallpaperService jar file.
    there is an exception come after running the code no wallpaper do ant draw task on 
    Screen----

```
02-16 11:09:31.941: E/AndroidRuntime(6286): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 9
02-16 11:09:31.941: E/AndroidRuntime(6286): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-16 11:09:31.941: E/AndroidRuntime(6286): at com.inoxmobile.waterlwp.WaterLiveWallpaperRenderer.onDrawFrame(WaterLiveWallpaperRenderer.java:152)
02-16 11:09:31.941: E/AndroidRuntime(6286): at    
com.inoxmobile.waterlwp.GLThread.guardedRun(GLWallpaperService.java:683)    
02-16 11:09:31.941: E/AndroidRuntime(6286):at com.inoxmobile.waterlwp.GLThread.run(GLWallpaperService.java:541)
```

I am using this code for that-----

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)
  {

    if (gl == null)
        return;

    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);    

    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    if (usebg) {
        gl.glDepthMask(false);
        mBackground.draw(gl);//Exception come Here..........
        gl.glDepthMask(true);
    }

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();    

    //if (usebg){
        //mBackground.Init(gl);
        //mBackground.setDims(mWidth, mHeight);
    //}
}
```

Comment: we should be looking at `mBackground` here, since you already checked `gl` earlier. What does `mBackground` contain anyway?

Comment: Could mean that mBackground is `null` if it didn't throw anything on `gl` variable before.

Comment: hi, mBackground is a Object of Background class in which draw method is present...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you certain you have initialized `mBackground` in `onCreate()` or the constructor of this class? Remember, if you only have a member declaration,

```
private Background mBackground;
```

this is equivalent to

```
private Background mBackground = null;
```